# Access 2016 VBA .FindFirst is not finding record in recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am new to programming and I'm trying my hand at writing some VBA code. I've been searching various sites and forums to help me accomplish my ultimate goal which is to have a code that will loop through a record set and update the corresponding records matching 3 criterion list boxes found on a form. Those values pass through to text boxes found on the same form where I can edit their values.

The current issue is I'm receiving the no match message box even though the record is in the record set. I'm looking for BC2 in the Day field. Unfortunately, I haven't found a similar issue on the sites and forums where I've been searching. Any assistance on this issue or in helping me accomplish my ultimate goal would be greatly appreciated! Below is the code I have thus far. A link to the picture of the record is found below the code.

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("LLT_TblDayInfo", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

    Dim strLookupValue1 As String
        strLookupValue1 = "[Day]= " = Me.lstDay.Value
    rs.FindFirst (strLookupValue1)
        If rs.NoMatch Then
            MsgBox "no records found"
        Else
            Do While Not rs.NoMatch
                MsgBox "i found it!!!"
                rs.FindNext (strLookupValue1)
            Loop
            rs.FindNext (strLookupValue1)
        End If
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gReEr.png)

Comment: what is Data type of Day is it Numeric or Text ? if Text you need to add single quote as suggested by Gustav

Comment: Thanks for your response Sham.  I now realize I need to be clear about the data type I'm working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do is to quote your text values using the correct syntax:

```
strLookupValue1 = "[Day] = '" & Me!lstDay.Value & "'"
```

Comment: That did it!  I spent days looking for a solution. I have a lot to learn. Thanks for you help!!